# How to get the applicationFrame minus the height of the UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

I put this in loadView and it works:

```
CGRect navFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
navFrame.size.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:navFrame];
```

But is there a variable like applicationFrame that gives the applicationFrame minus the UINavigationBar height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there isn't since three20 does something similar to what I did. In `TTGlobalNavigatorMetrics.m`, they do:

```
CGRect TTNavigationFrame() {
  CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
  return CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - TTToolbarHeight());
}
```

http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UINavigator/Sources/TTGlobalNavigatorMetrics.m#L53

Matt